# convert contents of a div to pdf

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to convert the contents in a `<div>` to a pdf.

The `<div>` contains information in various languages as well as images.

I want to use jQuery or C# asp.net.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

[MrRio/jsPDF Client-side JavaScript PDF generation for everyone.](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)

Simply include the jsPDF library in your , generate your PDF using the many built-in functions, then hook up a button to trigger the download. All the examples here use **jQuery**.

Comment: thanks for answer but i want to do as wikipedia export there articles tp pdf. they can also export articles which are in different languages.

Comment: does pdf care about the languages?